# How to plot a swarmplot of a grid of data, on one plot with seaborn

Tags: python, pandas, seaborn

I having been trying for ages to plot this data the way I want on seaborn, from a pandas dataframe. Any advice would be appreciated.

The Data is in a dataframe and looks like this, with 12 months, and 11 columns plus a month column:

```
  Month   FSRPX1M     VOX1M     XLB1M  ...     XLP1M     XLU1M     XLV1M     XLY1M
0   Jan  0.087643 -0.561428 -0.409286  ... -0.177143  0.232858  0.521428  0.457857
1   Feb  0.132429 -0.265715  0.470715  ...  0.067142 -0.479286 -0.177143  0.363571
2   Mar  0.152429  1.002142  0.437857  ...  0.588573  0.671428  0.055000  0.727856
3   Apr  0.150071  2.445000  1.331428  ...  0.551428  1.100715  0.790715  2.175714
4   May -0.089429 -0.115714  0.275000  ...  0.240000  0.113572  0.650716 -0.366429
```

What I want to do is plot a swarm plot, with Months along the X Axis, and the number along the Y axis, with 11 'dots' for each month, representing the 11 columns, with an associated a color coded key.

I have tried various things including [where df is the dataframe and val_list is a list of the columns I want as dots]:

```
sns.swarmplot(data = df, x=df['Month'], y = df[val_list])
```

and

```
sns.swarmplot(data = df, x=df['Month'], hue = df[val_list])
```

as well as trying to slice the dataframe, and make a plot, one column at a time using a for loop:

```
for e in val_list:
    sns.stripplot(data = df, x=df['Month'], y = df[e])
```

Any help and explanation of what I'm doing wrong would be great, thanks

The last one makes a plot, but all the dots are the same color and unlabelled

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To work with `hue`, Seaborn needs the data in ["long form"](https://seaborn.pydata.org/tutorial/data_structure.html#long-form-vs-wide-form-data).  Pandas' [`melt`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.melt.html) can be used to convert a "wide" dataframe to a "long" one. The `Set3` colormap has 12 colors (the default `tab10` only has 10).

```py
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

elements = ['Hydrogen', 'Helium', 'Lithium', 'Beryllium', 'Boron', 'Carbon',
            'Nitrogen', 'Oxygen', 'Fluorine', 'Neon', 'Sodium']
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(12, len(elements)), columns=elements)
df['Month'] = ['Jan', 'Feb', 'Mar', 'Apr', 'May', 'Jun', 'Jul', 'Aug', 'Sep', 'Oct', 'Nov', 'Dec']

df_long = df.melt(id_vars='Month', var_name='Element', value_name='Value')

ax = sns.swarmplot(data=df_long, x='Month', y='Value', hue='Element', palette='Set3')
ax.legend(bbox_to_anchor=(1.01, 1.02), loc='upper left', title='Element')
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

[image: sns.swarmplot with long dataframe]

Comment: Thanks, this was a perfect example, and easy to understand. I guess its a quirk of the 'hue' property in seaborn, which seems counter-intuitive to me, but the workaround is great!